# How to to convert GPS coordinates from UTM SAD69 to decimal SIRGAS2000?

Tags: google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

How would be the algorithm to convert the following GPS coordinates (Java language prefered)?

From `UTM/SAD69`:

`Latitude: 7171359,145
Longitude: 716431,81
Zone: 22
Hemisphere: South`

To `Decimal (Google Maps friendly)`:

`Longitude: -48.8461461196
Latitude: -25.559740724`

http://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=-25.559740724,-48.8461461196&hl=pt-BR&t=h&z=16

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [UTMConverter.java](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/73451bd7273d8b5ba949c4d0fb654ec6)  for that purpose, the following example:

```
double  easting = 716431.81;
double  northing = 7171359.145;
int zone = 22;
boolean isSouthHemishere = true;

LatLng value = UTMConverter.convertToLatLng(easting,northing,zone,isSouthHemishere);
System.out.println(value);
```

gives the same result (`lat: -25.55933783,lng:-48.84565751`) as [Geographic/UTM Coordinate Converter](http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html) online tool

Comment: Brazil has a deprecated coordinating system (SAD69) which require additional calculations/offsets, and the source code provided does not consider it. An online calculator is provided at http://www.dpi.inpe.br/calcula/

Comment: Your position is off by 66.04972117 m, it should be lat: -25.5597433731625, lng:-48.8461393141961

Answer (score 0):

Use PROJ.4 to convert from [EPSG:29192 (SAD69 / UTM zone 22S)](http://epsg.io/29192) to [EPSG:4326 (WGS 84)](http://epsg.io/4326).

For example [here](http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=29192&t_srs=4326&x=716431.81&y=7171359.145) is a simple interface to transform, but there are others for command line, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: The WGS still have ~0.5m difference over SIRGAS. See the table at the bottom of page http://www.ufrgs.br/engcart/Teste/refer_exp.html

Comment: @LuísRigoni You can change this to (e.g.) [EPSG:4170 (SIRGAS 1995)](http://epsg.io/4170), but I think the same is determined by PROJ.4